# How to increase performance of large number of updates to a redshift table with python functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a fairly large redshift table with around 200 million records.  I would like to update the values in one of the columns using a user-defined python function.  If I run the function in an EC2 instance, it results in millions of updates to the table, and it is very slow.  Is there a better process for me to speed up these updates?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike row-based systems, which are ideal for transaction processing, column-based systems (Redshift) are ideal for data warehousing and analytics, where queries often involve aggregates performed over large data sets. Since only the columns involved in the queries are processed and columnar data is stored sequentially on the storage media, column-based systems require far fewer I/Os, greatly improving query performance.

In your example instead of doing multiple separate `update`commands you can perform a single `update .. set.. from ... where ....`